# AutoHotKey - ImageSearch Two or more Images

Tags: autohotkey

I  have a simple script, and I am asking for help in expanding it.

I would like it to support more .png files but the operation is the same. please help

```html
; <COMPILER: v1.1.29.01>
SendMode Input
setmousedelay -1
setbatchlines -1
Loop
{
ImageSearch,ix,iy, 0,0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, mor.png
if !ErrorLevel
{
send {Browser_Back}
Sleep 100
}
}
return
F1::ExitApp
```

Comment: Are you wanting to send {Browser_Back} if one image is not present? or more than one image is not present? or all images are not present? Please explain exactly what you want to have happen and we can better assist you.

Comment: Hello,
Please, make more photos.
If image 1 appears, do a back browser
If the image 2 appears then back browser
If the image 3 appears then back browser

If there is no picture, it does nothing

Comment: If any of the images appears - Browser_Back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit the script below (`NewPic2.png` & `NewPic3.png`) to match the name of the pictures you have. If a picture is found, it will set `bT` variable to 1 (which is the same as true). If `bT` is true, `bT` will be set to 0 (same as false) and `{Browser_Back}` will be sent. If you want to check for more pictures, just add an additional `ImageSearch...` and `bT := ...` line per the pattern shown below. Please let me know if this works out for you.

```
SendMode , Input
SetMouseDelay , -1
SetBatchLines , -1
Loop
{
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , mor.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , NewPic2.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , NewPic3.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    If bT
    {
        bT := 0
        Send , {Browser_Back}
        Sleep , 100
}   }
Return
f1::ExitApp
```

Comment: Hello,
after a short test, I seem to be working!

is it possible for the script to work while loading the page?

Currently, he is starting work as the page loads.

Comment: Do you mean to detect the image before the page is completely loaded? It has to "see" the image for it to detect it, so it will have to be loaded via this method. If the image has a consistent web address, there may be other ways to detect it prior to load, but that is something I'd have to do a bit of research into.

Comment: Ok I understand.
Thank you for developing

Comment: hey, I have one more question ...
Is it possible to do instead of browser back, mause click on a specific .png? can you do that?

Comment: Yes. The first and second parameters of the ImageSearch command will store the X and Y values of the upper-left corner of the found image - which can then be used with the MouseClick command. If you need further help, perhaps ask a new question. Also, see [ImageSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) and [MouseClick](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm) from the help documentation.

Comment: and can you do such a script?
X1100
y350

Comment: If you would like me to make a script example that you can copy, please ask a new question so that I have the full set of formatting tools. Also, I'm not sure what you want me to do with "X1100 y350".

Comment: Hello,
What the script will look like. If I would like to ... bt = 0 true and bt = 1 false?

If bt = 1 false -
 Send, {Print_Screen}